# Проблемы с кодировкой в codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - два поля: почта и пароль от неё. Данные собираются и через пост отправляются в контроллер, там я провожу валидацию и делаю запись, через модель, в базу данных. Но, при записи одного из паролей, появилась ошибка. Символов было много, а на конце пароля такие `%ff`, и именно из-за этих символов почему-то через пост приходит пустота. Попробовал найти решение проблемы, нашёл лишь то, что это какой-то баг codeigniter, потому что `%ff` это шестнадцатиричное значение и дело в XSS фильтре, но решить так и не смог.
Ошибка связана с тем, что приходит пустой массив и выглядит таким образом `Message: Argument 1 passed to CI_Form_validation::set_data() must be of the type array, null given, called`

Comment: если в конфиге удалить строку `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` всё начинает работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что "`global_xss_filtering` является устаревшей и сохраняется исключительно для обратной совместимости версий. XSS экранирование должно выполняться на выводе, а не вводе" - пишут разработчики самого фреймворка.